# How to load a package at runtime

Tags: java, javafx

I creating an application which involves login of two types of users.
Upon login the application should load the respective UI. I searched
on the Internet for a solution , which involves using reflection
package. But that is either loading a main class and then invoking a
method , else load all classes. I have the code for those two types of
users in two different packages and currently i run the app with those
packages in already in the working directory(i.e under one project
name)

The final logic is that: i have three jars.

1. main.jar
2. admin.jar
3. tchr.jar

`main.jar` consists of login ui. after verifying the passwords the app
should load either `admin.jar` or `tchr.jar`

Im using javafx, and i want to use the same "Scene" object for
modification. I used a `BorderPane` with top as `Menubar` and center as
login. Both `admin.jar` and tchr.jar use a `GridPane` Upon login i intend
that (suppose user is admin) the BorderPane sets its center the
`GridPane` from `admin.jar`

Its much like how IDE uses its plugins, In Eclipse after downloading a
particular plugin the ide automatically recognizes the available
plugins and modifies the ui accordingly

Comment: Check [this](/help/mcve) before asking

Answer (score -1):

IF it is a commertial and industrial project I recommend you to use [OSGI](https://www.osgi.org/) as a dynamic modules solution. Otherwise you should take a closer look at Reflection&Java class loading to build your own lite solution.

To load UI dynamicly you should use [FXMLLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html). Store your GridPanes as a fxmls in your dynamic jar and then use similar code below to load them at runtime:

```
    public static Node loadResource(URL resource, Object controller){
    final FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(resource);
    if (controller!=null) loader.setController(controller);  
    try {
        Node node = loader.load();
        log.debug("resource {} loaded", resource);
        return node;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("could not load resource {}",resource, ExUtils.getRootCause(e));
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, its a personal project,I don't want to use FXML, and can u plz give some good links for java reflection tutorial

Comment: @NumaNuma See [How should I load jars dynamically at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime)